# ReactJS react-youtube mouseOver to play video isn't working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Today I ran into this problem. First, I want to point out every official usage is working well. But I want to use react event onMouseOver to trigger playVideo.

[Here's the code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Khmp.png)

Comment: You're binding your `onMouseOver` to the parent element instead of the `<Youtube` element. So `event.target` is going to be referring to that parent `div` instead. You should just bind it directly to the `<Youtube` element like they show here with `onReady` https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-youtube

Also, why an image when you can just paste in your code?

Comment: You are using string ref (deprecated) on a component not on a HTML video tag.

Comment: I thought it would show up in this post content, my bad. I will paste in my codes next time. And thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

After 2 days of trying and testing I got my problem fixed.

All I did is read through Youtube iframe API docs and applied.

In the end, I ditched react-youtube package and just use iframe tag to do my work.

Comment: I know it's years late, but would love to know how you addressed the issue, as I'm currently having trouble achieving this myself currently.